# Action bar implementation with ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to implement action bar on my **Android 2.1 API 7** project. (With Eclipse IDE)

In order to use **sherlock**, after I imported sherlock library as a existing project on Eclipse. I did the following things on my own project:

1. mouse right click on my project, choose "properties"
2. in "Android" section, there is "Library" sub-section, I added **sherlock** project as library
3. Apply change

Then, I notice the `FragmentActivity` can not be resolved in my project source code.

I checked the project property again, the added **sherlock** project as library is not in "Library" section...weired!!! **Why it suddenly disappeared even I have added sherlock as library?** What am I missing?

I mean no matter how many times I added **sherlock** as library to my own project, the next time I check project property, the sherlock just disappear from library section...

Comment: do you close the ActionBarSherlock project? You should keep it open.

Comment: So, it sounds like you successfully build the ABS library, but it never successfully applies to your project. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is not applied ,even I have added the sherlock library to my project in project properties  in Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, after adding the project as a library, restart Eclipse - I believe this is a known bug with at least some versions of the plugin.

If that doesn't work, check that the 'default.properties' file in your project root is not read only.

Comment: Hi, After I restarted eclipse, the sherlock is in the library of my project. Thank you.

Comment: FragmentActivity appears to have been introduced in Android 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Other known problems :

- Your app should use the same "Uses-sdk" setting in AndroidManifest like your Sherlock addon
- Minimum Java version for Sherlock: 1.6 !
- In package with libraries, you also have a lot of samples with source code
- ActionBar is not visible in Layouts

Few simple that i remember